# regex - define boundary using characters & delimiters

Tags: r, regex

I realize this is a rather simple question and I have searched throughout this site, but just can't seem to get my syntax right for the following regex challenges.  I'm looking to do two things.  First have the regex to pick up the first three characters and stop at a semicolon.  For example, my string might look as follows:

```
Apt;House;Condo;Apts;
```

I'd like to go here

```
Apartment;House;Condo;Apartment
```

I'd also like to create a regex to substitute a word in between delimiters, while keep others unchanged.  For example, I'd like to go from this:

```
feline;labrador;bird;labrador retriever;labrador dog; lab dog;
```

To this:

```
feline;dog;bird;dog;dog;dog;
```

Below is the regex I'm working with.  I know ^ denotes the beginning of the string and $ the end.  I've tried many variations, and am making substitutions, but am not achieving my desired out put.  I'm also guessing one regex could work for both?  Thanks for your help everyone.

```
df$variable <- gsub("^apt$;", "Apartment;", df$variable, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace whole words? Use word boundaries. `gsub("\\bapt\\b", "Apartment", df$variable, ignore.case = TRUE)`. Or do you need to specifically replace substrings in between semi-colons and start/end of string?

Comment: I think you should drop regex and use string-oriented functions.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, I'm looking to replace substrings in between semi-colons as well as words at the front of the string.  To elaborate on the second example, labrador could be published in many different ways including labrador retriever, labrador dog, lab dog, etc.  In sum, I need to create regex that will recognize the first three characters in the beginning and delimiter at the end.   Hope that makes sense.  Thank you.

Comment: I am still not sure, but try [`gsub("(^|;)[^;]*\\blab(?:rador)?\\b[^;]*", "\\1dog", x, ignore.case = TRUE)`](http://ideone.com/xgBaXA) - does that help? That matches the *whole field* that contains a whole word `lab` or `labrador` and replaces this whole field with `dog`.

Comment: Looks like that does not help. Please clarify.

Comment: Just tried that and couldn't get it to work.  When I use this code:  `gsub("lab.*", "Dog", x, ignore.case = TRUE)` it will replace all any words that contain `lab` but dog, but in doing so, removes all words after it.  I need to keep the words after intact, which is why I needed to define the delimiter boundary.

Comment: Why use `gsub("lab.*", "Dog", x, ignore.case = TRUE)` if I suggested `gsub("(^|;)[^;]*\\blab(?:rador)?\\b[^;]*", "\\1dog", x, ignore.case = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses look behind (so you need `perl=TRUE`):

```
> tmp <- c("feline;labrador;bird;labrador retriever;labrador dog; lab dog;",
+          "lab;feline;labrador;bird;labrador retriever;labrador dog; lab dog")
> gsub( "(?<=;|^) *lab[^;]*", "dog", tmp, perl=TRUE)
[1] "feline;dog;bird;dog;dog;dog;"   
[2] "dog;feline;dog;bird;dog;dog;dog"
```

The `(?<=;|^)` is the look behind, it says that any match must be preceded by either a semi-colon or the beginning of the string, but what is matched is not included in the part to be replaced.  The `*` will match 0 or more spaces (since your example string had one case where there was space between the semi-colon and the `lab`.  It then matches a literal `lab` followed by 0 or more characters other than a semi-colon.  Since `*` is by default greedy, this will match everything up to, but not including' the next semi-colon or the end of the string.  You could also include a positive look ahead `(?=;|$)` to make sure it goes all the way to the next semi-colon or end of string, but in this case the greediness of `*` will take care of that.

You could also use the non-greedy modifier, then force to match to end of string or semi-colon:

```
> gsub( "(?<=;|^) *lab.*?(?=;|$)", "dog", tmp, perl=TRUE)
[1] "feline;dog;bird;dog;dog;dog;"   
[2] "dog;feline;dog;bird;dog;dog;dog"
```

The `.*?` will match 0 or more characters, but as few as it can get away with, stretching just until the next semi-colon or end of line.

You can skip the look behind (and `perl=TRUE`) if you match the delimiter, then include it in the replacement:

```
> gsub("(;|^) *lab[^;]*", "\\1dog", tmp)
[1] "feline;dog;bird;dog;dog;dog;"   
[2] "dog;feline;dog;bird;dog;dog;dog"
```

With this method you need to be careful that you only match the delimiter on one side (the first in my example) since the match consumes the delimiter (not with the look-ahead or look-behind), if you consume both delimiters, then the next will be skipped and only every other field will be considered for replacement.

Comment: this is brilliant and works perfectly @Greg Snow!  Thank you!  Was unaware of look behinds.  Appreciate the time you spent providing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing this in two steps:

1. Split the string by the delimiters
2. Do the replacements
3. (optional, if that's what you gotta do) Smash the strings back together.

To split the string, I'd use the `stringr` library. But you can use base R too:

```
 myString  <- "Apt;House;Condo;Apts;"

 # base R
 splitString  <- unlist(strsplit(myString, ";", fixed = T))

 # with stringr
 library(stringr)
 splitString  <- as.vector(str_split(myString, ";", simplify = T))
```

Once you've done that, THEN you can do the text substitution:

```
# base R
fixedApts  <- gsub("^Apt$|^Apts$", "Apartment", splitString)

# with stringr
fixedApts  <- str_replace(splitString, "^Apt$|^Apts$", "Apartment")

# then do the rest of your replacements
```

There's probabably a better way to do the replacements than regular expressions (using `switch()`, maybe?)

Use `paste0(fixedApts, collapse = "")` to collapse the vector into a single string at the end if that's what you need to do.